# Double opt-in mailing list signup with Caldera Forms CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress, mailing, caldera-forms

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a "double opt-in" to a mailing list group workflow using Caldera Forms CiviCRM integration. Where the user would enter an email address into a field, then gets sent an email with a link they need to click to confirm they want to be added to the mailing list, and on doing so they're added to the appropriate group in CiviCRM. Essentially the same workflow as using a profile to sign up for a mailing list with the "Enable Double Opt-in for Profile..." settings checked.

Yes, one could just use a profile for this (and have in the past) but would prefer not to deal with the added security risk of enabling external form submissions. The mailing list signup form is in a sidebar widget, not a page, so using a shortcode isn't an option that I'm aware of. Even shorcode widget plugins don't seems to work for this purpose.

So, how would we set up a workflow to use Caldera forms to do this? We have it set up now in such a way that the user inputs their email address, and we use the Contact processor to process their email address and add them to a specific group. This works a treat, just want to explore options for the confirmation email step.

Thoughts? Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Jaap Jansmas integration of CiviCRM with the Form Processor](https://github.com/civimrf/cf-civicrm-formprocessor) for that: Just create a form processor using the action "Mailing Event: Subscribe to mailing list". You can even create simple deduplicating rules using conditions on the actions "Contact: Get Individual by name and email" and "Contact: Create or update Individual". The form processor will then appear as a Caldera Forms processor and you just add your slugs. Never forget to clear the CiviMcRestFace Log in Settings CiviCRM McRestFace Call Log when adding/changing form processors.

Update: Now Jaaps plugin can also be installed from the official Wordpress plugin repo:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf-civicrm-formprocessor/

Comment: It seems to me that the group you want to subscribe needs to be visible publicly. You can change this in the group settings. At the same the comment in the [code of the "Mailing Event: Subscribe to mailing list" action in the Action Provider Extension](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/action-provider/-/blob/master/Civi/ActionProvider/Action/MailingEvent/MailingEventSubscribe.php#L99-102) suggests that it should be possible even for non-public groups.

Comment: Indeed the group has to be public, otherwise the double-opt-in message won't be triggered by the Action "Mailing Event: Subscribe to mailing list".

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://wordpress.org/plugins/verify-email-for-caldera-forms/ to do that double opt in step.

Comment: From the FAQ: "Does It Got To Eleven?" A: "Of course it does." This looks like a solid option, we'll have a look.

Comment: Good, then vote the answer above so this is resolved.

Comment: I am sure that FAQ is an insider joke. lol

Comment: That plugin is no longer available. Is there any other solution out there?

Comment: Looks like they decided to monetize it https://calderaforms.com/downloads/verify-email/